# Does indexing on a part of a composite primary key is needed in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, primary-key, composite-primary-key, composite-index

I have a (large) table with a composite primary key, composed of 5 columns (a, b, c, d, e).

I'd like to efficiently select all rows having two of those columns (a + e) to a given value.

In PostgreSQL, do I need an index for this? Or will the database use the primary key (even partly?)

I've seen the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063493/relation-between-composite-primary-key-to-composite-foreign-key-which-is-a-part), which specify that MySQL can use the left-most part(s) of a multiple-column index for efficiently querying rows. But I did not find anything for PostgreSQL on composite primary keys.

Comment: Well, `(a,e)` is not the "left-most" part of the primary key. So Postgres won't be able to use an index on `(a,b,c,d,e)` efficiently. Details are [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html). I highly doubt that MySQL will use an index on `(a,b,c,d,e)` if the where clause specifies `(a,e)` - if it does, it probably only uses `a` (which Postgres can do just as well)

Comment: Well my remark on MySQL is not clear: it can indeed use the left-most part of the index, not "any" left-most part. For example it can use (a), (a,b), (a,b,c) and (a,b,c,d) if there is composite index on (a,b,c,d,e); bot none other. I'll remove "any" in my comment.

Comment: Postgres can use the same left-most parts. In addition it _can_ use the index for a condition on `(a,e)` (or even `c,d`) - but not as efficiently. Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) and you'll see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For best performance, you would need an additional index on `(a, e)`.

If that is an option, you can drop the primary key and replace it with one on `(a, e, b, c, d)`. The primary key index would then support your query, and it is just as good as far as uniqueness is concerned.

You can also experiment with a single-column index on `(e)`. PostgreSQL can combine scans on several indexes. That won't be as fast as a multi-column index, but the resulting index would be smaller.

Comment: Very good remark on a single-column index on (e) only. That could fit the bill as I need an index, but not a super-fast optimization.